# GTK signals from array of buttons C language

Tags: c, arrays, button, gtk

I've created an array of buttons in GTK in C, but I have a problem - how do I catch a signal from them?

```
 GtkWidget *board[10][10];
 for( i=0; i < 10; i++) {
        for( j=0; j < 10; j++) {
          board[i][j] = gtk_button_new();
        }
  }
```

I can, of course, do it one by one like that

```
  g_signal_connect (board[0][0], "clicked", G_CALLBACK(show_info), NULL;
```

But I'm planning to make a board game and there'll be 100 of buttons... Is there a way, it can be done in one function? For example, I'd like to change a color of button that was clicked, but I have no idea how to write a code for that.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: Couldn't you assign a function to them using function pointers?

Comment: @ShellFish can you explain what you mean?

Comment: @alcia The first argument of a signal handler is the object that generated the signal, so you can always know which button was pressed.

Comment: @andlabs but I don't want to write it like "board[0][1]" "board[0][2]"... etc. is there a way I could do it like "board[i][j]" and in the function "show_info" know somehow which button was clicked?

Comment: What is preventing you? You already have the double for-loops, just call g_signal_connect() there, right after you create the button.

Comment: @jku okej, I did it like you said, but what if I want to send the value of "i" and "j" in signal? I know what button was clicked, okay, but I have another array values[i][j] which keep some information about button I'd like to use when it's clicked.

Comment: You can either use a for loop to determine which button was clicked or pass `i` and `j` in a structure as your `user_data` (the last parameter of `g_signal_connect()`). Do note that if you do the latter you will need to keep the data memory alive yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it is to dynamically allocate some userdata to be passed to the callback.

```
typedef struct {
    int x;
    int y;
} coordinate;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // ... some code here
    for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
        for(j=0; j<10; j++) {
            coordinate *c = malloc(sizeof *c);
            c->x = i;
            c->y = j;
            board[i][j] = gtk_button_new();
            g_signal_connect_data(board[i][j],
                                  "clicked",
                                  G_CALLBACK(show_info),
                                  c,
                                  (GClosureNotify)free,
                                  0);
        }
    }
    // some other code
}
```

Then in the callback:

```
void show_info(GtkButton *button, gpointer userdata) {
    coordinate *c = userdata;
    // use c->x and c->y to determine which button is pressed
}
```

Comment: why G_MODULE_EXPORT? Just a copy-paste mistake maybe?

Comment: sure but for the given example it is unnecessary code and creates an unnecessary symbol export. I don't think adding G_MODULE_EXPORT to everything just in case is a good habit.